# Set Recording Format for AVAudioEngine in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

In Swift you can set a set a recording format using:

```
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: hwSampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: false)
```

I am struggling with how to do this in Objective C and autocomplete is not coming through either:

```
AVAudioFormat *newFormat = ???
```

(I need to create it in such a way as to set the sampleRate which is a readonly property.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
AVAudioFormat *newFormat = ((AVAudioFormat alloc) initWithCommonFormat:(AVAudioCommonFormat)format sampleRate:(double)sampleRate channels:(AVAudioChannelCount)channels interleaved:(BOOL)interleaved);
```

You can find it in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioformat?language=objc). You just have to select Objective-C as language in the top bar.